# Python: Trying to understand how this function works and what's its purpose

Tags: python-3.x

I have an assignment to explain the workings and doings of the following function. I am new to the world of programming and I am really having a problem understanding what the usecase of this function could be. I am also kind of lost trying to understand the steps of the function.

I have commentated on most of the actions that take place in this function, please feel free to correct me if I have gotten anything wrong or misunderstood anything.

```
def find(word, letter):
    # Function with 'word' an 'letter' as parameter
    index = 0
    # Set index to 0
    while index < len(word):
        # While index has a smaller letter count than then the given 'word', proceed
        if word[index] == letter:
            # If one of the indexed letters from 'word' is equal to 'letter', proceed
            return index
            # Return to index underneath here
        index += 1
        # Add the value of '1' to 'index' for every time the program loops through 'word'
    return -1
    # Here i have no clue
```

I really appreciate all help, I’m sorry for coming up with all of these noob questions but I got nowhere else to turn.

Comment: This is pretty broad. What specifically about the function are you having problems with? That line isn't very descript.

Comment: The question of the task is as following: 'What does the above function do?'

Comment: I got that. What about it don't you understand though? You must have studied the language enough to understand part of it.

Comment: If you take a look at the hashtags within the code, this is how i interperet the code. Am i at a right path at all or must i take some steps back to better my understanding.

Comment: The only part that's really unclear is the last line comment. -1 has historically been returned to mean "the element wasn't found in the list". If that's doesn't answer your question, you're going to need to be more explicit.

Comment: Thanks for all help, i think i must end this thread and then take some steps back to try getting a better understanding of the basics.

Comment: That's always a good idea. No offense, but every line of code here is pretty text-book. If you're having difficulties understanding any of the lines here, taking a step back will definitely be productive.

Comment: Thanks for your patience and help, have a good day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function is very simple, its role is to find the letter parameter in the word parameter, if you find the location of the return letter parameter in the word, if not found returns -1 means not found. If you are a newbie, you can start with the introductory tutorial, although you can find the answer here, but this is not the right way.